# git cvsimport with AuthReply: I Hate you error. Used cvs login but still fail

Tags: git, cvs, cvsimport

I tried to use git cvsimport with

```
git cvsimport -v -d :pserver:kuongkwan@PSLIS:/slis -r cvs -k SLIS
```

I tried the solution

```
cvs -d :pserver:kuongkwan@PSLIS:/slis login
```

already which has been posted before in stackoverflow by the others, but it fails.

It throws AuthReply: I HATE YOU error. I'm running in Windows 10. Any one know what's the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If even the `cvs login` step (`cvs -d :pserver:kuongkwan@PSLIS:/slis login`) fails, with a "I HATE YOU" error, that might means:

- you don't have access to the CVS repository
- you have the wrong password
- your password includes special characters that might need to be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters)

If the login succeeds, but the import fails, then, as in [`this thread`](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/cvs2git-migration-cloning-CVS-repository-td2258155.html), you might need to clone the CVS repository first with [`cvsclone`](https://www.samba.org/ftp/tridge/rtc/cvsclone.l).

Comment: 1. I can check out successfully using the command cvs checkout SLIS -d :pserver:kuongkwan@PSLIS:/slis

2. Tried many times for the password

3. No special characters